# Does the URL-Path change on facebook?

Tags: facebook, image, path

I want to read the URLs of Album images an display the images on my page.

When I have an image-path - e.g.: 
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/p720x720/13323555_1098089230248955_5014925174892795872_o.jpg - 
is this path "forever" like this or does facebook change some parts in the URL e.g. after a year?

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Facebook CDN URLs are to be considered “transient” – they can and will change over time.

So you should not store them for long-term use.

Use the `/picture` connection many of the nodes that deal with pictures/photos have, wherever possible - that way, the client you want to display the image on will be redirected to the correct, current address on the CDN automatically.